# Meaning? In logistic regression, testing "linearly related to log odds" results in a perfect 45 deg line, not a scatter plot

Tags: r, regression, logistic, assumptions, scatterplot

Running `glm(Cond1 ~ Level, data = Data1, family="binomial")` , I'm testing the assumption that B is linearly related to the log odds.  I'm getting a straight 45 degree line (not a scatter plot).  What does this mean?

I'm using the plot code from here: http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/36-classification-methods-essentials/148-logistic-regression-assumptions-and-diagnostics-in-r/
The resulting plots they show are scatterplots. The only difference in the code is the name of my dataset (Data1) in the first line, below.

[image]

```
mydata <- Data1 %>%
  dplyr::select_if(is.numeric) 
predictors <- colnames(mydata)
mydata <- mydata %>%
  mutate(logit = log(probabilities/(1-probabilities))) %>%
  gather(key = "predictors", value = "predictor.value", -logit)
ggplot(mydata, aes(logit, predictor.value))+
  geom_point(size = 0.5, alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  facet_wrap(~predictors, scales = "free_y")

> head(Data1)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Cond1  Level
  <fct> <dbl>
1 No     217.
2 Yes    226.
3 No     317.
...
```

Comment: Looking at plot(predictor.value, Data1$Level), the scattered points fall on a nearly straight line.  I think this is what's expected with a single, continuous predictor.

Comment: It appears the above comment is correct, as adding another predictor adds noise to the plot.

Comment: The standard plots that R generates for the results are more useful.